# how to rewrite this URL in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I just want to ask help if how to do this in .htaccess

sample:
https://sample.com/index.php?url=testimonials redirects to https://sample.com/testimonials

my htaccess rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home$ https://sample.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^url=testimonials$ https://sample.com/testimonials/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^error$ https://sample.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^1$ https://sample.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following. Considering that your htaccess file and index.php file both present in root folder(These rules were provided before OP shared other already present htaccess rules).

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @vince, it worked fine for me when I checked, do you have any other rules in your htaccess file? Kindly do let me know on same.

Comment: it returns This site can’t be reached in the inner pages like the services page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225026/discussion-between-vince-and-ravindersingh13).